# Make a class template a friend of itself for different instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I want to make `A<T>` a friend of `A<T2>` for any types `T` and `T2`.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'template+%3Cclass+T%3E%0Aclass+A+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T2%3E+void+test(A%3CT2%3E%26+a)+%7B+a.v_+%3D+2%3B%7D%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+v_%3B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T2%3E+friend+A%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++A%3Cint%3E+a%3B%0A++++A%3Cint%3E+b%3B%0A++++b.test(a)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.154046997389045,l:'4',m:71.89249720044792,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3+',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:48.99103139013454,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.00896860986548,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.84595300261096,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    template <typename T2> void test(A<T2>& a) { a.v_ = 2;}
private:
    int v_;
    template <typename T2> friend A;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    A<int> b;
    b.test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Error:

```
<source>:7:28: error: friend type templates must use an elaborated type

    template <typename T2> friend A;

                           ^~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
template <typename T2> friend class A;
```